# Leanplum with GCM and FCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, leanplum

Does Leanplum work with both GCM and FCM?

While users migrating users should get notifications on both platforms, is it possible?

Comment: Are you trying to use both together? You cannot use FCM and GCM libraries together — only one Leanplum push service per app. Check this [documentation](https://docs.leanplum.com/reference/javascript-push-notifications#android-setup) for more details.

Comment: I have current app version, it uses GCM, and I'm going to push new version that is using FCM. Is it possible to send pushes to GCM while users migrating from previous versions?

Comment: I think no, you must send pushes to FCM to communicate with users.